# Timing variations of percussive instrument performance

Tags: rhythm, percussion

I am at the final stages of my M.Sc. and I am working on a sonic gesture interaction system to control a digital percussion instrument (more like sampler). In order to perform the evaluation of the complete pipeline I have to compare the performance of an excerpt of a song using the interface with the original version. One of the factors I have to evaluate is the latency of the system, but in order to do that I have to "subtract" (or at least "take out" in a qualitative way) the variations in timing due to the instrumentalist's performance (something that happens naturally).

So the question is, what are the variations happening naturally in timing from one performance to the next for a percussive instrument? I understand that there is not a specific number to be given but I am interested at the order of magnitude (is it in the order of up to 5 ms or in the order of 20 ms, etc.).

Some information about the piece and the player are that the piece is a "rock" piece (in the sense that it is modern popular music), the player will be playing on top of a backing-track (with the original drums channels included), they are an amateur musician with not so much experience.

I would also really appreciate any recommendations on available literature related to the topic.

---

### Update

After some comments, I would like to provide some information on the system. The latency of the system is constant and about 1.6 ms which is exactly the latency imposed by the audio interface for the specified sampling rate and frame size (44.1 kHz and 128 samples respectively).

I understand that performers do adapt their playing based on various factors (including but not limited to other players, groove, etc.). This, in addition to the inability of a player to adapt correctly (or efficiently) to various factors may lead to timing (beat) offsets, the order of magnitude is what I would like to know. Tetsujin have suggested getting averages over many performances of various genres and performers and, although I strongly support the idea as a valid and correct one, getting those numbers is not the topic of my work. I am looking for the order of magnitude of the timing "errors" (apologise for the abuse of term to include also correctly performed rhythmic expressions).

It would be beneficial to the work to find numbers corresponding to similar musical genres to the one performed in the experiment but this is of minor importance for the main focus of the work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135121/discussion-on-question-by-zaellixa-timing-variations-of-percussive-instrument-pe).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your latency is a fixed value [I hope]. Anything else will be a good player compensating for that latency, or a bad player flailing & failing. A good player can move within the groove to push or pull a performance to suit. A bad player will just wander around within it, hoping that on average it will be OK.

Generally, for percussion your latency has got to be under 10ms, hopefully 5. Over that & your player will spend half their concentration pre-empting the feel rather than actually feeling it. If your latency varies, chaos will ensue.

I think the only way you're going to gauge this discrepancy practically is to measure how several different percussionists of varying skill can handle the structure.
From comments - make sure you don't confuse groove/feel with latency.
You might to have to test a good repertoire of music types as well as players to be able to average that out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well as the comment on the question. I have clarified my question a bit to make you sure that I do get the difference between latency and groove. I have been working as a sound engineer for more than 10 years now and I all concepts you have mentioned are clear to me. I am just looking for the order of magnitude of timing variations to support the fact that any timing offsets are only to a minor degree due to the implemented interface.

Comment: I'd have thought ten years as a sound engineer would have given you a pretty good insight into all you ask!

Comment: @Tim I do have a personal opinion on the matter and some insight but I wouldn't like to throw personal opinions without some "scientific" support into my Thesis. Additionally, insight cannot quantify any results and undocumented claims are not easily supported. These are some of the reasons I am looking for some articles/papers to include in the text.